# How to include a file, but not execute everything?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on making a few amendments to a website.
The way the website currently works is that the page calls for a require once for the  `config.inc.php` page.  The config page also has the SQL call for the what is required to show from the database.  While this works fine, I need to create a new page that shows the same table, but the SQL has changed to show different data.

The trouble I’m having is that the `config.inc.php` page has the SQL data on it that pulls in what is wanted.  I want to show a different result on a different page, but the website requires the `config.inc.php` to show everything. I changed the SQL query to test if what I wanted to show will work and it works a charm, but how do I get this to show without having to mess around with the original SQL command.

Here's the original code;

```
    $config = require_once 'link to admin section';
$db_username = $config['components']['db']['username'];
$db_password = $config['components']['db']['password'];

$db_link = mysql_connect('nosey', $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('nosey', $db_link);

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
  if ( isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] ) {
    $selectSqlJSONString = 'SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'].' ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1';
    $jsonResult = mysql_query($selectSqlJSONString, $db_link);
    $jsonRow = mysql_fetch_object($jsonResult);

    if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) )
        include 'details_ajax_header.php';

    include 'filename.php';

    if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) )
        include 'details_ajax_footer.php';

    exit;
  }
}
$region = '1';
if ( isset($_GET['region']) && $_GET['region'] ) {
  $region .= ' AND ' . sprintf('county LIKE "%%%s%%"', mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('-', ' ',$_GET['region']), $db_link ));
}

$selectSqlString = 'SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE '.$region.' ORDER BY created DESC'; 
$result = mysql_query($selectSqlString, $db_link) or die(mysql_error());

$vacancies = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  $vacancies[] = $row;
}
```

and here's what I would to show only on another page to show a different set of results.

```
    $config = require_once 'link to admin section';
    $db_username = $config['components']['db']['username'];
    $db_password = $config['components']['db']['password'];

    $db_link = mysql_connect('nosey', $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('nosey', $db_link);

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
      if ( isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] ) {
        $selectSqlJSONString = 'SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'].' ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1';
        $jsonResult = mysql_query($selectSqlJSONString, $db_link);
        $jsonRow = mysql_fetch_object($jsonResult);

        if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) )
            include 'details_ajax_header.php';

        include 'filename.php';

        if ( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) )
            include 'details_ajax_footer.php';

        exit;
      }
    }
    $region = '1';
    if ( isset($_GET['region']) && $_GET['region'] ) {
      $region .= ' AND ' . sprintf('county LIKE "%%%s%%"', mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('-', ' ',$_GET['region']), $db_link ));
    }

   $selectSqlString = 'SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE featured = "1" ORDER BY created DESC';
    $result = mysql_query($selectSqlString, $db_link) or die(mysql_error());

    $vacancies = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
      $vacancies[] = $row;
    }
```

Notice how all I want to change is the `SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE featured = "1"`.

This is all I need! But I want to include this without having to alter the `config.inc.php` page!  (**which is where this information is coming from**) How do I do it?

Comment: Simple - don't require the default config file on the page you're editing. Make a new copy with the same connection code but without the query, and carry on as normal.

Comment: I'd say, make it conditional; immediately above `$selectSqlString = ...`, insert this line: `if (we are on my very special page) $region = 'featured = "1"';` The condition could be based on a parameter, or (quite dirty) on the name of the page.

Comment: Ruud, that sounds very promising.  How do I do that? The page is called featuredJobs.php.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I don't think I can agree with that. Why put the connection code into more than one file? It just means that when you need to change it, you need to change it in multiple places. Kind of defeats the purposes of using separate function-based files at all.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please pick one (though I don't think platform is relevant in any case).

Comment: Aaron i'm using MySQL